# Sum up multiple columns of names from single column of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel Example
[image]

Given the same list of names in multiple columns, is it possible to use the `sumif` command to sum the total, given a single column of numbers? For example, in the image attached, Mason should=69, yet it only sums the first column. Let me know if I can do anything else to clarify this. If `sumif` is not ideal, what can be used instead?

Comment: If it's a small set, you could just put this in `J1`, and drag down: `=SUMIF(C:C,I1,A:A)+SUMIF(D:D,I1,A:A)+SUMIF(E:E,I1,A:A)+SUMIF(F:F,I1,A:A)+SUMIF(G:G,I1,A:A)`...

Answer (score 2):

Another, better, way than my comment is, in `J1`, enter this array formula:

`=SUM(IF($C$1:$G$30=I1,$A$1:$A$30))`
(Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) and drag down

Comment: Without the need for CSE:

    `=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$G$30=I1)*($A$1:$A$30))`

Comment: Thank you, Scott's formula worked. Now, if I were to add last names to each first name, is it still possible to sum products based on first name only?

Comment: @tculler - Yeah, just use `Left()` with `Search()`. Say you have "Bruce Wayne" in the `J1`, change the `I1` reference in either formula to `TRIM(LEFT(I1,SEARCH(" ",I1)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - And with great ideas/formulas like that, it's no wonder you have 50k rep :D.  Thanks for that, I'll have to try and remember that for the future.

Comment: Bruce, I've been playing with the Trim/Left/Search formula you dropped, but can't get it to work. Is there something wrong here? SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$G$30=TRIM(LEFT($C$1:$G$30,SEARCH("Mason",I1))))*($A$1:$A$30)). Pretty lengthy and although it solves now, the result is 0. Should still be 69

Comment: @tculler - `=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$G$30=TRIM(LEFT(I1,SEARCH(" ",I1))))*($A$1:$A$30))`... Ah - I'm thinking the last names are *just* in the "search" column. If you add last names to the main data, it's probably easiest if you just add a helper column next to them showing the first name only (use the same trim/left formula)

Comment: Bruce - The trim/right only removes a number of characters that I designate, correct? Is there a way to remove the entire last name and the space, since the length of the last name varies?

Comment: @tculler - `Left()`/`Right()`/`Mid()` *can* remove a specific number of characters, but I'm using `Search(" ",...)` to search for the first space. Using `=TRIM(LEFT(I1,SEARCH(" ",I1))` should *only* return the first word/name.